# Erro em evento JS para forçar e renomear arquivo de Download

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Olá, possuo um Script de forçar download via URL remota que consegui como resposta aqui no site, contudo acho que eu devo ter feito algo errado pois o evento de Download não está iniciando e nem mesmo renomeando o arquivo na hora de baixar.

**Atualização:** Com a ajuda do Dontvote  o script esta efetuando o download o caso só falta renomear o arquivo da Url Remota de resto esta ok, alguém teria como me ajudar com isso.

**Observação** mudei o código na pergunta de arquivo de imagem para arquivo de vídeo.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
.hide-link {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0px;
   left: 0px;
}
</style>   
 <script>
function download(url, nome) {
    var el = document.createElement("a");
        el.download = nome; //Define o nome
        el.href = url; //Define a url
        el.target = "_blank"; //Força abrir em uma nova janela
        el.className = "hide-link"; //Adiciona uma classe css pra ocultar

    document.body.appendChild(el);

    if (el.fireEvent) {
        el.fireEvent('onclick');//Simula o click pra navegadores com suporte ao fireEvent
    } else {
        //Simula o click
        var evObj;

        evObj = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
        evObj.initEvent("click", true, false);
        el.dispatchEvent(evObj);
    }

    //Remove o link da página
    setTimeout(function() { document.body.removeChild(el); }, 100);
}
</script>
<div class="hide-link" onload="download('http://thumb.mais.uol.com.br/14317945.mp4', 'video01.mp4')">Clique aqui</div>  
</body>    
</html>
```

Comment: E você debugou a função, ou verificou se tem algum erro no console?

Comment: Testei o script em vários sites de Teste de script online e em 4 servidores a função não foi iniciada de forma alguma.

Answer (score 1):

Está dando erro nesse momento:

```
evObj.initEvent(type, true, false);
```

Porque a variável `type` não está definida. Testei colocando `"click"` *hard-code* e funcionou:

```
evObj.initEvent("click", true, false);
```

<kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6dneu7s7/)**</kbd>

Como eu havia dito, o elemento [`div`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/div) não possui o evento [`onload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/load). Quando você postou o código usando um `button` com `onclick`, a função funcionou.

Comment: Ata erro meu ja editei coloquei evento onclick

Comment: @Rodrigo veja minha edição.

Comment: @Rodrigo você não para de mudar seu código, assim não tem como ajudar. Coloquei um fiddle com seu código funcionando da forma que eu falei.

Comment: O evento de Download esta funcionando só que não esta renomeando o arquivo na hora de baixar. Só falta isso mais grato pela ajuda ate agora.

Comment: @Rodrigo bom, de acordo com [essa documentação(veja *notes*)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-download): *"This attribute is only honored for links to resources with the same-origin."*, então provavelmente não irá funcionar por você estar fazendo a requisição para um servidor de terceiros.